# Azure SQL Database "Could not find stored procedure 'sp_linkedservers'" through SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, ssms, azure-sql-database

I've had this error for months now. On some databases on my Azure SQL Server, when I go to Edit Rows or enter Designer view in SQL Server Management Studio. I get an error

> **Could not find stored procedure 'sp_linkedservers'**.

I don't know where it's looking or what stored procedure to add.

Comment: The easy solution is to stop using the visual row editor. Just write the update statements you need instead. The visual row editor has some strange bugs that pop up occasionally. You should do the same with editing tables.

Comment: That's a good point but when I'm just hopping in to change something from true to false or some other minor change, it's a lot faster to just open and edit that single cell than to find the ID and write the statement. Bulk updates, sure but there's a lot of convenience in this feature.

Comment: I find it faster to do it with t-sql than the gui. I have SSMS open already most of the time so a simple update is way faster than digging through the list of tables and such to edit the top x rows (and worse if the row you want isn't in there). Once you are more comfortable writing t-sql you will find it is much faster.

Comment: What version of SSMS is this? I don't have this issue on SSMS 2014

Comment: It's 2014. They started out just fine for several months and without explanation 4 or 5 of them just started throwing the error. I've tried the uninstall/install process. Different machines with new installs. Still reporting the same thing. I'm sure it's DB side just can't figure out why or how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone but the "stop using the visual editor" is not an answer to the question. I know how to write my SQL statements, I simply have a preference and an error I need to clear.

Comment: Hey Tom, if you have a consistent way to reproduce the error, I would suggest filing a bug on the [Microsoft connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback). Also as an aside, I'm using the [SSMS October preview release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290.aspx), and I haven't run into the bug, maybe you could give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't a solution for SSMS 2014, working through SSMS 2016 CTP3 seems to be working and the problem has been solved. Thanks to @Cpt. Monac for the suggestion!

Comment: here's where one can get the latest version of SSMS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: I installed the March 2016 SSMS preview from the above link, but I am still having this problem, although strangely the first time I selected "edit rows" it worked fine.